Proving that $\ker(f) = \ker(g \circ f)$
I am working through the exercises in Mathematics for Machine Learning by by Marc Peter Deisenroth, A. Aldo Faisal, and Cheng Soon Ong for self-study. I am struggling with one of the exercises:
Let $E$ be a vector space. Let $f$ and $g$ be two automorphisms on $E$ such that $f \circ g = ID_E$ so that $f \circ g$ is the identity mapping $ID_E$. Show that $ker(f) = ker(g \circ f)$
I get that f and g are automorphisms so that f and g map onto themselves and also g is the inverse of f and vice versa. I don’t know if I’m overthinking it at this point, but is it as simple as the null space of f must be the same as its identity matrix by defintion? I’m not sure what I’m missing.

$g$ is not the inverse of $f$ nor $f$ is the inverse of $g$. That would be true if we know that $g \circ f = \text{id}_E$.

Just show that $\ker(f) \subseteq \ker(g \circ f)$ and that $\ker(g \circ f) \subseteq \ker(f)$. For the latter you need to use the fact that $f \circ g = \text{id}_E$.

Aren’t automorphisms isomorphisms by definition and thus have trivial kernel? Do you mean endomorphisms?

In general, given two functions $g:X\to Y$ and $f:Y\to Z$ so that $(f\circ g):X\to Z$ is injective, then $g$ is injective too. Indeed, such claim can be proven as follows. Suppose that $x_{1}\in X$ and $x_{2}\in X$. On the assumption that $f\circ g$ is injective, it results the desired property:
\begin{align*}
g(x_{1}) = g(x_{2}) \Rightarrow f(g(x_{1})) = f(g(x_{2})) \Rightarrow (f\circ g)(x_{1}) = (f\circ g)(x_{2}) \Rightarrow x_{1} = x_{2}
\end{align*}
and we are done.
In the particular case where $f$ and $g$ are linear mappings, we know that $g$ is injective iff $\ker(g) = \{0\}$. Hence:
\begin{align*}
v\in\ker(g\circ f) \Rightarrow (g\circ f)(v) = 0 \Rightarrow g(f(v)) = 0 \Rightarrow f(v) = 0 \Rightarrow v\in\ker(f).
\end{align*}
In other words, $\ker(g\circ f) \subseteq \ker(f)$. The reverse relation does also hold because:
\begin{align*}
v\in\ker(f) \Rightarrow f(v) = 0 \Rightarrow g(f(v)) = 0 \Rightarrow (g\circ f)(v) = 0 \Rightarrow v\in\ker(g\circ f)
\end{align*}
that is to say, $\ker(f)\subseteq\ker(g\circ f)$, and we are done.
Hopefully this helps!
